# Jenkins won't start up after being stopped

Tags: jenkins

I installed Jenkins yesterday (together with apache2). Jenkins started fine and everything was ok. Then I decided to stop jenkins and apache because I planned to configure them today. Now when I start Jenkins i get this error:
[Jenkins startup error](http://pastebin.com/8gBypFPz)

I have tried some other Ports like 8081 or 4xxxx, nothing helped.
How can i fix this? Please help.

System:

- Debian 6.0
- Installation of Jenkins through the offical repo.
- Apache has no vhosts except the 000-default
- netstat shows nothing on 8080 or the 4xxxx Port

Comment: This is not a programming question. StackOverflow is specifically for programming questions.

Comment: Hello David, thank you for your comment. Before I posted this questions i investigated a lot of and found a bunch of questions in Stackoverflow which have the same type as mine. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is quite easy to pin:

> Caused by: java.net.BindException: **Address already in use**

This means that for the given address:port there is already a process which is binding to it. Please, use the operating system tools to find this process and, eventually, kill it. Then start Jenkins again.

Additionally, I can add, that it almost certainly Jenkins, which was not stopped correctly or, due to some error, did not stopped entirely.